# Create a function that is a Tuple of two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file that has 6 lines of numbers:

```
1,35,1,0,3,1,1.09,5,5,1,0
0,22,1,0,6,4,1.15,5,6,2,0
2,35,1,1,0,1,1.14,6,2,3,0
0,38,1,0,4,3,1.09,3,1,1,0
2,37,1,0,3,3,1.13,4,3,1,0
```

The function that needs to be printed out is D = (X,y)
X for example using the first line would equal:[0,27,0,1,7,2,1.09,6,5,3] 
y for example using the first line would equal: [0] (the last number of that line

I am trying use the values of X and y and make it into this form:
D = (X,y)

How do I do this?

This is what I did which gave me the X and y values

```
    y_list = []
    x_list = []
    for W in range(0,100):
        X = f.readline()
        y = X.split(",")
        #print(y)
        y_list.append(y[10][0])
        z_list = []
        for Z in range(0,10):
            z_list.append(y[Z])
        x_list.append(z_list)
    print (y_list)
    print (x_list)
    f.close()
```

How do I combine both the X and y values properly where it matches D = (X,y)?

For example using the first line
D = ([0,27,0,1,7,2,1.09,6,5,3] , [0])

Comment: `D = x_list, y_list`?

Comment: Not exactly. I tried that using tuple and it became all of the x_list values, all of the y_list values. It doesn't match. It needs to be like this: D = ([0,27,0,1,7,2,1.09,6,5,3] , [0], [0,22,1,0,6,4,1.15,5,6,2], [0], [2,35,1,1,0,1,1.14,6,2,3], [0], [0,38,1,0,4,3,1.09,3,1,1], [0], [2,37,1,0,3,3,1.13,4,3,1], [0])

Comment: Could you please show the result if there are two lines

Comment: @user20304030 This comment is completely different than what you ask in the question (`D = (X,y)`). Please post your actual expected output.

Comment: I don't understand how x will be equal to `[0,27,0,1,7,2,1.09,6,5,3] `. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

```
fo = open('value.txt',"r")
D = []
for l in fo.read().split('\n'):
    values = l.split(',')
    D.append(values[:-1])
    D.append([values[-1]])
print(tuple(D))
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Nicely done, one comment: remember to close the file